# Duplicate related list records and put it in another related list. Both having same parents

Tags: apex, related-list, duplicate-management

I have a requirement where a related list records needs to be duplicated and put in another related list where both are related to the same parent. Has anyone built it?

Comment: Are you trying to build it on a `Visualforce Page`?

Comment: Looking for ideas to build this actually. Can this be done by having a custom button on the first related list and on it's click, the records under them are cloned to put them on the other related list? @AdrianLarson

Comment: Its possible and quite common functionality, what have you tried so far?

Comment: The parent being opportunity, I wanted to clone the opportunity under each opportunity and insert those records to another custom object which is in a lookup relationship with Opportunity object. @RahulSharma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to do this in Apex, here is how you can accomplish this. First Query all the child records, clone them and add them to a List. Insert the List so that it will create another related list.

```
String parentId = Parent.Id;
// Query for all Child records  
String query = String.format(
    'SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE Claim__c = \'\'{2}\'\'',
    new String[] {
        String.join(
            new List<String>(
                Child__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet()
            ),
            ','
        ),
        String.valueOf(Child__c.SObjectType),
        parentId
    }
);
List<Child__c> children = new List<Child__c>();
try{
    for (Child__c child:(List<Child__c>)Database.query(query)) {
        children.add(child.clone(false,true,false,false));
    }
    if (!children.isEmpty()) {
        System.debug('Child List  successfully cloned!');
    }
    for (Child__c child : children) {
        child.Claim__c = Parent.Id;
    }
    //Insert the Child Records
    Database.insert(children);                
}catch(Exception ex){
    System.debug(ex.getMessage());
}
```